# Access is denied when working with a 3rd party iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

My page calls an iframe. This iframe has the code:

```
window.parent.parent.resizeIframe(height);
```

When oppening my page, I get an error saying `Access is denied` pointing to the above line of code.

It only doesn't work with IE.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the iFrame on the same domain as the parent? Cross site scripting protection ensures that iFrames can't access their parents (and the parents can't access the internals of the iFrame) unless they're on the same domain.

Comment: The are on different domains. But why the problem is only in IE. Chrome and Firefox seems to work fine